# Getting error while trying to extract .dmg file using 7zip

Tags: 20.04, 7zip

I'm getting problem when I'm trying to extract .dmg file. I'm getting an error:

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=pl_PL.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3530  @ 2.16GHz (30678),ASM)

Scanning the drive for archives:

ERROR: No more files
SF-Font-Pro.dmg

System ERROR:
Unknown error -2147024872

I'm using 7z x file.dmg command and I'm keeping the Apple fonts in my .fonts folder (it's hidden in home, but I have them unhidden when I had it in downloads folder and documents it still didnt work)

Comment: What's the exact command that you're using to extract the files?

Comment: 7z x SF-Font-Pro.dmg

Comment: Assuming you got that [direct from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), the file should have a sha1 hash of `956b3e1b361deb2aa2cb8ea14fa94742af740263`. When I extract this on my machine, it works just fine — which doesn't help you very much. Silly question, but did you install the `p7zip-full` package?

Comment: yes i did install

Comment: Can you confirm the file is valid? There's a possibility you have an incomplete download: `sha1sum SF-Font-Pro.dmg`. You should get the same value that I shared earlier.

Comment: sha1sum: SF-Font-Pro.dmg: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
                                              (There is no such file or directory)

Comment: You're running that from the same directory that contains the `SF-font-Pro.dmg` file, yes?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not native english speaker

Comment: No problem. What I mean is that you need to run the command from the same directory that has the `SF-Font-Pro.dmg` file or clearly state it’s location. So, if it’s in your `/Downloads` directory, open terminal and type: `sha1sum ~/Downloads/SF-Font-Pro.dmg`. That will give you a long string. You can compare it against the I sent to see if the file is corrupted.

Comment: oh ok I will try that

Comment: But still I have the same message sha1sum: /home/damian/Downloads/SF-Font-Pro.dmg: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
( There is no such file or directory)

Comment: oh nvm i have different laungauge than english

Comment: i have this 956b3e1b361deb2aa2cb8ea14fa94742af740263  /home/damian/Pobrane/SF-Font-Pro.dmg

Comment: And its same as the one above

Comment: Let's add one more package for 7zip, then: `sudo apt install p7zip-rar`. I have both `-full` and `-rar` on my system, so perhaps this is why I can extract it but you cannot.

Comment: I still can't extract it